# URLConnection timeout error works fine on local, but not on dev server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, timeout, urlconnection

For some reason I receiving `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out` from the following code below. It works fine on my local computer, and I can access it via the browser both on my local and dev server, however on the dev server I get this error when trying to read it.

```
public List<NodeMap> downloadFile(String fileUrl) {

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {

        URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        con.setReadTimeout(60000);
        inputStream = con.getInputStream();

        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream),',','"');

        return iterateRows(csvReader);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Node mapping file", e);
    }
    finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Full Stack**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
```

Comment: May be in your browser configuration on dev server there is also a proxy configuration and that's why it works from the browser and not from the program?

Comment: Close the csvReader istead(which it should close the inputStream also)

Comment: I dont know what that means by proxy configuration.

Comment: What it means is, your browser does not directly access the web server. In the browser settings, you can add a proxy server IP and all requests will then be routed through that. If you're using chrome, go to settings -> advanced settings -> network -> change proxy settings -> LAN settings. If there is a proxy configured there, that should be used in your code as well.
Also, the URL you're accessing, where does it run? Local or Dev? Did you try the code in your local computer and did that run successfully?

Comment: No proxy is in my browser.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Yes it runs locally just fine as I stated in my question, the URL also looks fine printed out in the server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a DNS issue.  I used the internal IP of the url, and it worked!